# How do I make a Windows 10 Recovery Live USB that can boot from Secure UEFI containing file size over the FAT32 limit on Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, live-usb, windows-10, secure-boot

**Update 3**

- The latest ISO file size (November 2019, 1909 build) is greater than my 2 brands of burnable DVDs that can only handle 4.7 GB.
- From my research knowledge. UEFI will only show bootable USB devices with FAT32 system. I've tried manually copying the files but one is over 4 GB in the ISO which FAT32 don't support.
- Took me a while but I figured out in order to turn off Secure Boot. I had to set a Supervisor Password. But even with it disabled it doesn't show the NTFS drive even with boot and esp flags set in gparted.
- I've tried a dd write from ISO to /dev/sdb but that didn't seem to work.

I have had the GRUB Repair tool boot off the USB with the help of Rufus on Windows. So I know the USB storage can be used.

I have a 32 GB USB and the Windows 10 ISO ready. I just need to know how to make it work.

Comment: What ISO is >4.9 GB.  You mentioned Xubuntu in the title, but the latest Xubuntu ISOs I have are 1.6GB in size (including later ones dated this year, this month).

Comment: The Windows 10 ISO is 5.5 GB. Sorry if I missed anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get Windows 10 ISO to run off USB.

- I moved the Windows 10 ISO to broken installed Windows 10 with Xubuntu.
- I then used Rufus on ISO and wasn't aware it had an NTFS option when I thought I recall there was only FAT partitions available when I made the Boot-Repair USB.
- I entered a Supervisor Password in BIOS which allowed me to finally turn off Secure boot. (I don't get why it's even needed.)
- Then I can either:

  - Add the EFI by adding trusted TCM (I think it was called) - but only if Supervisor Password is enabled and Secure Boot is enabled.
  - Or clear the TCM entries which will cause other OS like Xubuntu to disappear from EFI boot list.
- Then finally just set boot priority to USB media and running through installation with no issue. Had to take note before starting this procedure of which partitions were used by Windows and which were Xubuntu and my shared NTFS partition that both OS can access with my files.

Installation and updates were much faster using a newer build. For precaution I used "O&O ShutUp 10" to stop any driver updates (excluding OS security) once my graphics driver started to work.

I can't believe how tedious it was trying to get an ISO to boot from an USB. I've noticed that even Microsoft's Media Creator tool page is no longer available.

Answer (score 2):

> My BIOS doesn't allow me to turn off secure boot either.

There are no known x86 "BIOSes" that don't allow you to turn off *Secure Boot* (because, a few years ago, there was a lot of backlash when Microsoft tried to enforce such a policy on ARM hardware). So it's **exceedingly** unlikely that you found one.

However, there exist "BIOSes" that hide the disabling of *Secure Boot* behind other options (such as first needing to set an Administrator password for some Acer hardware).

You probably want to take a look at [this list](https://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#disable) from Rod Smith's very comprehensive web site about EFI boot, as you'll probably find the information you seek on how you should proceed for disabling *Secure Boot* on your platform.

Once you have *Secure Boot* disabled (which only needs to be temporary — You can re-enable it once Windows is installed), then you will be able to boot in UEFI mode from an `NTFS` partition (through [UEFI:NTFS](https://github.com/pbatard/uefi-ntfs) which is what woeusb and Rufus use behind the scenes) and therefore be able to use your Nov 2019 Windows image.